# protobuf.net c# obervablecollection

Tags: c#, collections, protobuf-net

I am trying to get my observablelist which is derived from observablecollection to be serialized. For some reason the collection has always 0 Elements when I deserialize it. When I change the collectiontype from observablelist to observablecollection in class "Test" it works fine. So, how can I achive that my class is also handled like a normal list. Hope anyone can help me. Here is my Code:

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    ...
}    

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableList<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; } = new ObservableList<Hobby>();
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

KR Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use this Class it's not working but, if i rename the Add() function to AddRange() for example it is. Can anyone tell me the reason for this strange behaviour?

```
public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{ 
    public void Add(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            Add(item);
    }
}
```

protobuf-net needs to support arbitrary lists / collections - not just those that derive from `List<T>` or support specific interfaces. It does this by attempting to resolve a suitable `GetEnumerator()` method (for serialization) and `Add()` method (for deserialization). There are more than a few checks and priorities built into this, but it sounds like *in this specific case* it is getting confused as to your intent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine here... using your code, and:

```
static void Main()
{
    var test = new Test
    {
        Hobbies =
        {
             new Hobby { Name = "abc" }
        }
    };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(test);
    Console.WriteLine("Same object? {0}",
        ReferenceEquals(test, clone));
    Console.WriteLine("Sub items: {0}",
        clone.Hobbies.Count);
    foreach (var x in clone.Hobbies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
    }
}
```

gives the output:

```
Same object? False
Sub items: 1
abc
```

So: the deserialized object has the correct sub-item.

Comment: sorry, i used the wrong collectiontype in my example Code, if i use observablelist instead of a normal list, it's not working! I changed it in my question.

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth it is working fine in my [code here](http://pastie.org/10736871). Can you show a *full example* of it not working, so I can see what you are seeing? I wonder whether the real problem here is the classic "didn't rewind a stream" issue...

Answer (score 0):

I found out whats going on. Here again my Observablelist Class:

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class ObservableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{ 
    public void Add(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            Add(item);
    }
}
```

If I use this Class it's not working but, if i rename the Add() function to AddRange() for example it is. Can anyone tell me the reason for this strange behaviour?